# Strange assembler generated by VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, assembly

I have a c++ function, looking like:

```
inline unsigned short function_name(float x, float y, someStruct *cfg) 
{
    int x_pos = (int)(x*2 + 0.5f);
    int y_pos = (int)(y*2 + 0.5f);  

    int dict_index = x_pos + (y_pos * cfg->subdivisions_adj);

    [...]
```

while `someStruct` is declared as:

```
struct someStruct {
 int subdivisions;
 int subdivisions_adj;
 [...]
}
```

The generated assembly for the third line (`int dict_index = [...]`) is:

```
cvttss2si edi,xmm3
imul edi,[ecx+04h]
movss xmm3,[ecx+0ch]
movaps xmm4,xmm3
mulss xmm4,xmm0
addss xmm4,xmm1
cvttss2si eax,xmm4
add edi,eax
```

(See also the [result by AMDCodeAnalyst](http://s22.postimg.org/6z1inyvr5/screenshot_137.png))

Can anyone explain what this assembly does? I don't know why `cvttss2si` and `movaps` are used at all, aren't they for floating point numbers?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7, with the SSE2 instruction set enabled.

Comment: But what do they do / why are they neccessary? I thought they were mainly for floating point numbers

Comment: But they are converted to int's before .. or is that done in the assembly, too? I don't really have assembly knowledge.

Comment: You can find out what they do [in Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?wapkw=(Intel+Architecture+Software+Developer%E2%80%99s+Manual)91)

Comment: The processor doesn't understand C++, so anything that can't be calculated at compile-time has to be done through machine code (of which assembly code is a human-readable representation).

Comment: Are you sure that assembly is generated for **THAT line**? Moreover to inspect assembly generated at line level I suppose you're using a **debug build** (and that surprises me because of SSE...)

Comment: This is the full assembly: http://s22.postimg.org/yc6piq2bl/screenshot_138.png . I'm using a release build with /debug enabled. My problem is, I am trying to optimize that line, because it takes more time than all other code-lines in the function.

Comment: Addendum: well they (x_pos and y_pos) have been calculated with SSE so compiler emits code to manage that results (because they're still in xmm registers)

Comment: So they are just moved to xmm registers, not converted to int at all? And only when they are used to calculate `dict_index` they're converted?

Comment: In release build it's not easy to understand what happens (because of optimizations that may even be cross-function). Anyway that line of course is longer than the others because it has to **deference a pointer**, **performs a float->int conversion** (even if it may be "assigned" to the other line) plus an add and a mul (same as the others).

Comment: Yes. they stay "float" until used but it has not so much sense to say this because they're used immediately (would be less confusing to assign conversion to previous lines but...)

Comment: That makes sense .. I did not now optimisation goes so far to even merge code lines.. Thanks! :)

Comment: The compiler will "mingle" lines together when optimising, so you have to follow each variable from the entry to it's use to understand what goes on. This is partly done to reduce register pressure (don't have to "remember" so many things in registers, and partly done to "hide latency" - long running instructions are moved up to a point well before their use, so that the processor doesn't have to "wait for the answer". For example `imul` that takes about 5-10 clock cycles to complete, so we can throw a few other instructions in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is simply that the compiler merges the first three lines together into one intermingled sequence of instructions.

```
cvttss2si edi,xmm3
```

Convert xmm3 as `float` to 32-bit `int`. Presumably xmm3 contains the float value of `y_pos`, and this is the result of `(int)` on the calculateion of `y_pos`.

```
imul edi,[ecx+04h]
```

Multiply by `cfg->subdivisions_adj` (ecx = cfg, subdivisions_adj = offset of 4)

```
movss xmm3,[ecx+0ch]
```

Would be part of the ... in your `cfg` variable, I suppose.

```
movaps xmm4,xmm3
mulss xmm4,xmm0    
adss xmm4,xmm1
```

calculate x_pos = x * 2 + 0.5

```
cvttss2si eax,xmm4
```

(int) x_pos;

```
add edi,eax
```

Add x_pos to y_pos * cfg->subdivisions_adj;

Comment: Thanks! I assumed the whole time they were converted to floats before. Now it makes more sense for me :)